# Google map api v3: Onclick of a button make the polygon uneditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have polygon that can edited but I need an option to make the same polygon static i.e. not editable by user so that I can show the markers within the drawn polygon.
I tried setting `editable: false` but this doesn't help

Is there a way to do this?

Code below:

```
drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    drawingControl: false,
    polygonOptions: {
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillOpacity: 0.2,
        editable: true,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        geodesic: true,
        suppressUndo: true
    },
    polylineOptions: {
        editable: true,
        suppressUndo: true
    }
});
```

Onclick event

```
$('#showRes').click(function(){
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
    drawingManager.setOptions({ 
        polygonOptions: {
            paths: pathArr,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            editable: false,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            geodesic: true,
            suppressUndo: true
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes there is a way.  What does your code look like?  [map with edit "toggle" button](http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test5.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get this working thanks to geocodezip for providing demo link:

```
   drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
   drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
    drawingControl: false,
    polygonOptions: {
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillOpacity: 0.2,
        editable: true,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        geodesic: true,
        suppressUndo: true
    },
    polylineOptions: {
        editable: true,
        suppressUndo: true
    }
});

google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
    myPolygon = polygon;
}

$('#showRes').click(function(){
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
    myPolygon.setOptions({ editable: false });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you used `setOptions()` in your answer.

More directly, you can use the the `setEditable(bool)` method.